Iterate a Python Dictionary
I have the following method :
def apply_encoding_and_validate_size_of_items_of_list(self):
    list_with_sizes = []
    for key, value in self.dictionary_of_tasks.items():
        if not value:
            raise Exception("[ERROR]: missing field: {}".format(value))
        self.dictionary_of_tasks[key] = value.split(",")
        size_of_list = list(self.dictionary_of_tasks[key]).__len__()
        list_with_sizes.append(size_of_list)
        self.dictionary_of_tasks[key] = [item.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8') for item in self.dictionary_of_tasks[key]]
        set_with_sizes = set(list_with_sizes)
        if set_with_sizes.__len__() == 1 :
            print("I am Groot")
            self.dictionary_of_tasks
        else :
            print("I am green")
            sys.exit(1)
    return self.dictionary_of_tasks

In a different script, I import the original script with the method above.
I trylu believe that the method above returns a dictionary.
In any case, in the script below, I am not able to iterate this dictionary :
control_flow = ControlFlow(releaseVariable)
dictionary_encoded = control_flow.apply_encoding_and_validate_size_of_items_of_list()
for key, value in dictionary_encoded.iter():
print(value)
Can someone help me please ?
